# Could someone help me make a script that could structure files in folders (and subfolders) depending on their names?

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

I know there exist quite a lot of script out there to do such tasks, but I couldn't find any that can do what I am specifically searching for...

I am looking for a script that could read all files I have in a folder, separate all "_" and put them into subfolders.

The structure of the filenames look like this:

```
Clothes_Man_Citizen_Pants.png
Clothes_Man_Citizen_Top.png
```

The script would then create subfolders with this structure:

```
Clothes/Man/Citizen/Clothes_Man_Citizen_Pants.png
Clothes/Man/Citizen/Clothes_Man_Citizen_Top.png
```

I am asking this because I couldn't find any photoshop script to export nested groups in photoshop... So I'm exporting all the layers into a folder and would like to create the nested folder structure with a batch or something like that.

Thanks for your answers !

EDIT:

In pseudo-code it would look like this:

```
InitialName = Clothes_Man_Citizen_Pants.png;
TempName = Clothes_Man_Citizen_Pants.png;

While (There is an underscore in TempName) {
    -> Read name until underscore
    -> Create folder with name
    -> Get into created folder
    -> Remove part from TempName
    -> Repeat
}
```

When there are no underscores anymore in TempName paste the file with InitialName in the last created folder.

Comment: do you have always 3 parts of the path, not 2 or 4?

Comment: So far I have tried applications like FileToFolder or robobasket but these don't do what I want :/ No the parts can vary that's the problem...

Comment: I would need kind  of a regex function to read the amout of underscores, create folders for each part and finally add the file to the last path (last subfolder)

Comment: Please reword your question to be about software development.  Right now the primary topic is "I am looking for an existing script" which has nothing at all to do with StackOverflow.

Comment: No problem, it's done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in (*.png) do (
        rem Retrieve file name and extension
        set "fileName=%%~nxa"

        rem Prepare the folder from filename
        rem Filenames not splitted by underscores will be skipped
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
        for %%b in ("::\!fileName:_=\!") do endlocal & if not "%%~pb"=="\" %"% ( set "folder=%%~pb" ) else ( set "folder=" ) 

        rem If we have a target folder, ...
        if defined folder (
            rem We need a mask to move all the files in a folder in one command

            rem First remove leading and trailing backslashes
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
            for %%b in ("!folder:~1,-1!") do endlocal & set "mask=%%~b"

            rem Now replace backslashes with underscores and add wildcard and extension
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
            for %%b in ("!mask:\=_!") do endlocal & set "mask=%%~b_*.png"

            rem Create the target folder and move the files 
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
            if not exist ".!folder!" md ".!folder!"
            move /y "!mask!" ".!folder!" 
            endlocal 
        )
    )
```

This takes the file name, replaces the underscores into backslashes and uses the generated string as a folder hierarchy to do all the operations.

The `setlocal / endlocal` are needed to handle the posibility of exclamations (`!`)  in the name/path of files. If it will never be the case, delayed expansion (needed in the code) can be enabled from the start and the previous code can be reduced to

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in (*.png) do (
        set "fileName=%%~nxa"
        for %%b in ("::\!fileName:_=\!") do if not "%%~pb"=="\" %"% ( set "folder=%%~pb" ) else ( set "folder=" )
        if defined folder (
            set "mask=!folder:~1,-1!"
            set "mask=!mask:\=_!_*.png"
            if not exist ".!folder!" md ".!folder!"
            move /y "!mask!" ".!folder!" 
        )
    )
```

*note*: in both codes you can find `%"%`, that is not needed. It is included only to correct the syntax hightlighting that fails because the `"\"` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**EDIT**: The original code had a bug. It is fixed now...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.png) do (
   set "filename=%%a"
   for %%b in (!filename:_= !) do set "lastPart=%%b"
   for %%b in (!lastPart!) do set "filename=!filename:_%%b=!"
   md "!filename:_=\!" 2> NUL
   move "%%a" "!filename:_=\!"
)
```

This method will fail if the file names may include spaces, comma or semicolon. It also remove exclamation marks.

Comment: I tried your script but nothing is happening :/ I have no idea why... I got MC ND's script to work so it's alright, but I would like to thank you anyway for your help :D

Comment: Ops! The code had a bug! It is fixed now, so you may copy it again and test it. If you do so, look at _the time_ it take to move your files...